# c# Implicit Generic Types with 2 Keys

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, repository-pattern

I am writing a generic repository for C# and Entity Framework and I am trying to get this code to work without adding a whole bunch of extra interfaces.

Essentially, I have a class called `HavePrimaryKey<TKey>` which ALL the database entities inherit from:

```
public class MemberInfo : HavePrimaryKey<int>
```

As you can see, they can define what type of primary key the class uses.

This allows me to do:

```
public interface IDbGenericIdRepository<T, TKey> : IDbGenericRepository<T>
    where T : HavePrimaryKey<TKey>
```

However, this means I need to define EACH and EVERY key when I create the repository:

```
IDbGenericIdRepository<MemberInfo, int>
```

When, in reality, it would be much nicer to be able to have the compiler IMPLY the second type from the fact the first type MUST inherit from the 2nd type:

```
IDbGenericIdRepository<MemberInfo>
```

e.g. in the above case, as `MemberInfo` inherits from `HavePrimaryKey<int>`, then it HOPEFULLY will IMPLICITLY pick up that it needs an int... but instead it simply moans and says 'requires 2 type arguments'

ONE way to fix this is to use a different repository for each type:

```
public interface IDbGenericIntIdRepository<T> : IDbGenericRepository<T>
    where T : HavePrimaryKey<int>

public interface IDbGenericStrIdRepository<T> : IDbGenericRepository<T>
    where T : HavePrimaryKey<string>
```

etc... but I am hoping there might be a less brute force way to manage this?

Any ideas?

Many thanks,

Phil.

Comment: The compiler cant read your mind unfortunately. However, the main problem here is you are using a generic repository over EF. Its kind of like running away from the circus to join the orphanage

Comment: In your `HavePrimaryKey` class, do you need it to be `T` or could you use `Type`? i.e. nowhere in your code do you do `typeof(T)`?

Comment: How exactly are you going to use the HavePrimaryKey<T> interface?

Comment: Can you share your `HavePrimaryKey` class? Also, just to confirm whether you are using `EntityFramework` or `Entity Framework Core`.

Comment: Yeah I would just do an interface, not a base class like this. Although as people above pointed out a generic repo over EF is a bit of an anti-pattern

Answer (score 0):

I understand your thought process, you interfaces are very similar to something I've tried in the past. This guide sums it up though:

> [Generic Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-interfaces) - Generic classes can implement generic interfaces or closed constructed interfaces as long as the class parameter list supplies all arguments required by the interface

Its all good for them to say that, but in practice it makes sense... Using your definition:

```
public interface IDbGenericIdRepository<T, TKey> : IDbGenericRepository<T>
    where T : HavePrimaryKey<TKey>
```

Then we are explicitly defining the Generic condition of `T` *on* another generic condition `TKey`. That means that we need to explicitly define the type argument `TKey` for the compiler to be able to check that the type of T is valid at all.

We have created a dependency here, `TKey` and `T` are not the same type, `T` however must implement a version of `HavePrimaryKey`, this interface doesn't care specifically what the actual type of `TKey` is, only that the class that implements the interface MUST define it.

You still want to know *why* though don't you...

Basically where Interface inheritance is concerned, we need to be aware that a class that implements one (or more) interfaces can actually present a different implementation for each member of each interface and a different implementation for the class itself!

So now we'll introduce a simple implementation of `HavePrimaryKey<TKey>` and some example classes that *implement* this interface in different ways, all are valid in the eys of the compiler.

```cs
public interface HavePrimaryKey<TKey>
{
    T PrimaryKey { get; }
}

public class MemberInfoInt : HavePrimaryKey<int>
{
    public int PrimaryKey { get; }
}

public class MemberInfoString : HavePrimaryKey<string>
{
    public int PrimaryKey { get; }
    string HavePrimaryKey<string> PrimaryKey { get; }
}
```

Another valid implementation, however absurd is this:

```
public class MemberInfo3 : HavePrimaryKey<int>, HavePrimaryKey<Guid>
{
    public string PrimaryKey { get; }
    int HavePrimaryKey<int>.PrimaryKey { get; }
    Guid HavePrimaryKey<Guid>.PrimaryKey { get; }
}
```

So now if we try to implement this using your preferred notation, we can start to see the dilemma: *Note, this is not valid*

```
public class Repo : IDbGenericIdRepository<MemberInfo3> ...
```

In this instance the compiler tries to evaluate `typeof(MemberInfo3) == HavePrimaryKey<?>` and it fails there, it cant even *compile* the expression that is supposed to be used to validate the first expression.

There is no way *(other than the one legal way we already know)* to tell the compiler which specific type implementation we intend to use to validate that `MemberInfo3` is valid to use for a condition for `T`.

---

C# is strongly typed, that's what we all love (or love to hate) about it, so where there is the possibility of ambiguity, it is in our nature to force and expect a strongly typed definition for our types and classes.

That is why you MUST provide all the generic type arguments from the inherited interfaces.